# With $N$-component vectors, would you choose $({ u }^{ T }v){ w }^{ T }$ or ${ u }^{ T }(v{ w }^{ T })$?

Tags: linear-algebra

**This question was taken from MIT OCW and *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang**

Suppose $A$ is $m$ by $n$, $B$ is $n$ by $p$, and $C$ is $p$ by $q$. Then the multiplication count for (AB)C is $mnp + mpq$. The same answer comes from $A$ times BC with $mnq + npq$ separate multiplications. Notice $npq$ for $BC$

b) With $N$-component vectors, would you choose $({ u }^{ T }v){ w }^{ T }$ or ${ u }^{ T }(v{ w }^{ T })$

Can someone explain to me what this sub question is asking in regards to the first statement? I don't understand how b) has anything to do with what was first said about matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: Your vectors are $n \times 1$ matrices. Your transposed vectors are $1 \times n$ matrices.

Comment: It's a question related to optimizing the performance of a computation.  The question is "which of these two ways of multiplying out $u^Tvw^T$ requires your computer to calculate the least number of multiplications?"  So first count the number of multiplications required to compute $\alpha = u^Tv$ (for instance a $1\times 2$ matrix multiplied by a $2\times 1$ matrix requires only $2$ multiplications) then add the number of multiplications required to compute $\alpha w^T$.  Then do the same for $u^T(vw^T)$ and see if you can figure out which requires less total individual multiplications.

Comment: As to how this question relates to the paragraph above it -- it is a special case of the above where $m=1$, $p=1$, and $n=q$.  (Which BTW should help you check your answers.)

Comment: @Bye_World That's what I thought at first, but then I started to doubt myself. So, $({ u }^{ T }v){ w }^{ T }$ would look like this? $([{ x }_{ 1 }{ x }_{ 2 }...{ x }_{ n }]\cdot \begin{bmatrix} { x }_{ 1 }   \\ { x }_{ 2 }   \\ { x }_{ n }  \end{bmatrix})[{ x }_{ 1 }{ x }_{ 2 }...{ x }_{ n }]$

Comment: Yes -- except the components need not all be the same, of course.

Comment: So in terms of the analysis of $({ u }^{ T }v){ w }^{ T }$. We need $n$ multiplications to get the dot product of $({ u }^{ T }v)$. Then we need another $n$ multiplications to get the dot product of $({ u }^{ T }v)$ and ${ w }^{ T }$. In total this requires $2n$ multiplications. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.  Notice that when you count up the multiplications in $u^T(vw^T)$ you should get a different number.

Comment: @Bye_World Feel free to add what you wrote as an answer. I will approve it and +1. I now see the application of this in computer science thanks to your explanation.